# Link_to post method is converted to get

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After some time off Rails, i am creating a 3.1 rails project now. I pasted some code from a previous project to create a link_to that posts a value, but i can't get to have the correct behaviour for some reason, and i don't see why. The link_to is (building_controller):

```
<%= link_to "Upgrade", upgrade_building_path(:id => construction.building.id), :method => :post %>
```

ROUTE :

```
  scope :path => '/building', :controller => :building do
    post 'upgrade' => :upgrade, :as => 'upgrade_building'
  end
```

This actually gives me a :

```
No route matches [GET] "/building/upgrade"
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Are you load the rails ujs javascript (Either via the prototype-ujs or  jquery-ujs libraries, depending on whether you are using prototype or jquery)

Comment: just jquery-min and ui from what i can see now. (unless it's automatically added somehow)

Comment: Hope this helps :) => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315465/rails-3-link-to-generator-for-post-put-delete

Answer (score 1):

Following Prair's comment above, the solution was :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

new technologies in rails every 3 months i guess, sprockets this time :P