# How to add form parameter in Rails link with PUT method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

Right now, I have the following and it works:

```
<%= link_to 'stop service', service_path(:id => @service.id, 'service[stopped]' => true, method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The link looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/services/1?service%5Bstopped%5D=true`

So the `service[stopped]` parameter gets submitted to the server as part of the query string. I need it to get submitted though as a POST/PUT form parameter instead. I tried adding `'service[stopped]' => true` inside the `data` hash, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<%= link_to 'stop service', service_path(:id => @service.id, 'service[stopped]' => true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) , :method => :post %>
```

You can refer [Rails 3 link_to generator for :post, :put, & :delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315465/rails-3-link-to-generator-for-post-put-delete)