# better way to hide passed parameters in url than 'params.except'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, parameters

I'm really confused about how rails passes parameters to GET-requests.
I have a rails app with a login form. If a user wants to login with a default test user, he/she can click on a link which passes the test-email and the test-password.

The following works well:

```
<%= link_to "test login", login_path(:email => "test-email", :password => "test-password") %>
```

When this is clicked, the login pages loads with the email- and password-field prefilled.

The problem is, that both the email and the password will be shown in the url.
Yesterday, this worked for me:

```
<%= link_to "test login", login_path(params.except(:email => "test-email", :password => "test-password")) %>
```

Today, without having changed the code, the parameters are not passed when I use `params.except`.

So, how can I ensure that the parameters will be passed but not shown in the url?

**Edit:**
problem solved. see my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5333786/525478

Comment: GET request always show parameters in URL...
As you want to click with default username and password then create your one own routes suppose (default_login)
and in that method authenticate your request with default one.

Comment: Well, as mentioned above, it already worked for me. When using `params.except`, parameters will be passed but not shown in the url (url: `.../login?action=foo&controller=bar`. I didn't change this but it stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. Added the following to my `routes.rb`:

```
get 'test_login' => 'sessions#new', :email => "the test email", :password => "the test password"
```

So i just can call `<%= link_to "test login", test_login_path %>`
This will transmit the default email and password and prefill the login form, but the url will just be `.../test_login`

In my opinion, that's way smarter than `params.except`.

Comment: Do you know a way of doing this with dinamic values? where the `:email` and `:password` depend on variables.