# Rails3 Routing Error. :method => :delete, It will be "no route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I want to call a destroy action. It is already define in controller.
The model that I want to destroy is nested resource. But route is existing in `rake routes` result.

```
  new_content_model GET    /contents/:content_id/model/new(.:format)                         {:controller=>"models", :action=>"new"}
 edit_content_model GET    /contents/:content_id/model/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:controller=>"models", :action=>"edit"}
      content_model PUT    /contents/:content_id/model/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"models", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /contents/:content_id/model/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"models", :action=>"destroy"}
```

And I call destroy action from this url

```
<%= link_to "destroy nested model", content_model_path( @content.id, @model.id ), :confirm => "are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

It is no route matches.

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/contents/1/model/1"`
```

Please tell me some solutions.

---

Already wrote `<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>` in layouts/application.html.erb

[Rails 3 link_to (:method => :delete) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342083/rails-3-link-to-method-delete-not-working)

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong.  The next thing I would do is look at the log after trying to follow the link, and see if that reveals anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.
It was wrong that I deleted `rails.js` and `prototype.js`.

Thank you for your attending. Sorry for lack of information.