# No route matches [GET] "/logout" [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I get the following routing error when I click on "logout":

```
No route matches [GET] "/logout"
```

This is my application.html.erb file:

```
 <% if session[:user_id] %>
      <%= link_to 'Logout', logout_path, :method => :delete %>
    <% end %>
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
  controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login'=> :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
  end

  get "sessions/create"
  get "sessions/destroy"
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you enabled the built-in JavaScript libraries that are required (jquery/jquery_ujs)? The delete method is not directly supported by browsers, so this ends up actually creating a form with a hidden field _method, that Rails interprets to direct you to the correct place.

Comment: Promoted my comment to an answer...

Comment: change `delete 'logout' => :destroy` to `get 'logout' => :destroy` this will work.

Comment: @Kingstone
Thank you very much ;) It works!

Answer (score 11):

change `delete 'logout' => :destroy` to `get 'logout' => :destroy` this will work.

Comment: I'm running a 4.0.4 rails version and there are these two lines. But thanks for help. @Kingstone solved that problem :)

Comment: @Koin Arab, Jack's just trying to get you to mark the right answer

Comment: It's 2023 and I ran into a similar issue while working on a Rails 7 app.  Based on the solution offered this is what worked for me:  `get 'logout' => 'login#destroy'`

Answer (score 9):

Have you enabled the built-in JavaScript libraries that are required (`jquery`/`jquery_ujs`)? The `delete` method is not directly supported by browsers, so this ends up actually creating a form with a hidden field `_method`, that Rails interprets to direct you to the correct place.

**Edit:**

To enable these libraries, check your application layout file. This is usually located at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, but this may vary if you've customised your app.

You'll need to have the following tags in the `head` section:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

That should get this working for you, but if not, post back and I'll try to help further. It'd be useful if you could get your code online - on GitHub or somewhere else - so that we can all see what you're trying to do in context.

Comment: No i haven't. How do I enabled it?

Comment: For Rails 5.1 all I had to do was add `//= require rails-ujs` to my **application.js** file.

Answer (score 0):

For the version RoR 7.0.4 and higher

1. Add to the *app*/**assets**/*javascript*/**application**.js

   ```
   //= require rails-ujs
   ```
2. In the file *app*/**views**/*layouts*/**application.html.erb** put the rows to into comment such or delete it

   ```
   <!--%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %-->
   <!--%= javascript_importmap_tags %-->
   ```
3. Add the new rows *here*

   **<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>**

And all will be work.
Have a nice day)

Answer (score 0):

It is 2023 and I had the same problem.
I am with rails 7.0.8 my code is
`delete "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy"`

I had to change it to
`get "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy"`

and it works. I honestly have no idea why it works but it does. Makes no sense to me why we have to send a get request instead.