# The difference between delete and the other routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below I have the link-helpers for the actions edit and destroy. The first link (and all the others) is working perfectly but the second creates a weird url that doesn't work.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(organizer_vanity_url: event.organizer.vanity_url, id: event.id) %>  
<%= link_to 'Remove', event_path(organizer_vanity_url: event.organizer.vanity_url, id: event.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

This is from the routes.rb:

```
scope "organizer" do
  scope ":organizer_vanity_url" do
    scope "manage" do
      resources :events
    end
  end
end
```

What is the difference between the delete link-helper and the others (as that's the only one that doesn't work)?

Comment: `oorganizer` instead of `organizer`?

Comment: Same solution as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606860/rails-3-link-to-to-destroy-not-working

Comment: @Peter Alfvin That's just a typo in the example code.

Comment: @polmiro button_to? As I have nested routing, I need to pass params to build the route, don't I?

Comment: Yeah but the button_to will make a POST request, which is needed to use the method DELETE as @okliv mentions in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link_to` - is GET-request-like helper (by default)

`DELETE` method is POST-like method

so, you passing post method to get helper and receive "weird url"

to solve this you have two options:

- use `button_to` instead of `link_to` helper (first one is for post form submitting, by default)
- [use js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342083/rails-3-link-to-method-delete-not-working) to correctly handle your link.