# Rails HTML requests :Post but does a :Get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post, get, request

I have some code for attending/withdrawing from a competition:

```
<% if @competition.users.exclude?(@user)  %>
  <%= link_to 'Attend Competition', attend_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on the action I go to an error page:

```
No route matches [GET] "/competitions/1/withdraw"
```

Why isn't it doing a POST request? How do I fix this?

Not sure if it effects it, but my current js is

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

thanks

Comment: what is the generated html ?

Comment: from inspector: <a href="/competitions/1/withdraw" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">Withdraw</a> ///// excuse any typing errors as I couldn't copy/paste it

Comment: put `//= require turbolinks` before `//= require bootstrap
` and then try.

Comment: no luck with this solution

Comment: Do you have javascript disabled in your browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342083/rails-3-link-to-method-delete-not-working

Comment: why post duplicate questions? There is a link "edit" below tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123512/rails-sends-get-request-when-it-should-be-post