# Rails sends GET request when it should be POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that is supposed to send a POST request, but for some reason is sending a GET.

View:

```
<% if @competition.users.exclude?(@user)  %>
  <%= link_to 'Attend Competition', attend_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def attend
  p current_user.daily
  @competition = Competition.find(params[:id])
  if @competition.users.include?(current_user)
    flash[:error] = "You're already attending this competition."
  elsif current_user.daily == []
    flash[:error] = "You must have a working device to compete."
  else
    current_user.competitions << @competition
    flash[:success] = "Attending competition!"
  end
  redirect_to @competition
end

def withdraw
  p "WITHDRAWING"
  @competition    = Competition.find(params[:id])
  p @competition
  attendee = Attendee.find_by_user_id_and_competition_id(current_user.id, @competition.id)
  if attendee.blank?
    flash[:error] = "No current attendees"
  else
    attendee.delete
    flash[:success] = 'You are no longer attending this competition.'
  end
  p attendee
  redirect_to @competition
end
```

Routes:

```
resources   :competitions do
  post 'attend', on: :member
end

resources :competitions do
  member do 
    post 'withdraw'
  end
end
```

So I click on the button and go to the page, but get an error that there is no route for a GET request. There shouldn't be a route for get requests, but it should be sending a post.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/competitions/1/withdraw")
```

Comment: Do you have javascript disabled in your browser?

Comment: From rails documentation for link_to: `Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET`

Comment: What javascript do I need to enable? I have Jquery, but do I need Jquery-ujs or Jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to run:

```
 rake routes
```

That will show you all your available routes and their methods.  I believe since you are doing a post to a method other then create that it is not understanding what you are trying to do.  I am looking to see if I can find the proper way to do this, but I did find that the Rails documentation says:

> If you are relying on the POST behavior, you should check for it in your controller's action by using the request object's methods for post?, delete?, :patch, or put?.

So you may need to check for a post in your controller action.  I looked for an example of how to do this but couldn't find anything.

Looking at your routes, it should work the way you have it.  One other thing to try is to use "put" instead of "post."

One other option that you may want to consider is to make it a form and style the button like a link if that is the look you are going for.

Mike Riley